# A question of greatest common divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $a$ and $b$ are not both 0.

Prove that $gcd(a,b)=1$ if and only if there exist $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that   $au+bv=1.$

How can we prove this?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: This is a very useful theorem and well known theorem known as [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: @JackM I was just about to write the same think:)

Comment: @AYARcom you have asked several questions, but You are not accepting any answer. You should accept the answer that people give to your questions, otherwise people wont answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof:

the set $U =\{au+bv, u,v\in \Bbb Z\}$ is stable under substraction and product by elements of $\Bbb Z$.

Consider its lowest $>0$ element $X$. Divide by $X$ any element $x\in U$ you get
$$
x = qX + r
\\
0\le r <X
$$
Using stability, you get that $r=0$. Hence $U = X \Bbb Z$.

Note that the Euclide algorithm proves that $\gcd(a,b)\in U$, hence
$X| \gcd(a,b)$. But also, $X = au_X + bv_X$ hence $\gcd(a,b)|X$.

$$
\{au+bv, u,v\in \Bbb Z\} = \gcd(a,b)\Bbb Z
$$

---

Now get back to the problem.

$$\gcd(a,b)=1\iff \gcd(a,b)\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z
\iff \{au+bv, u,v\in \Bbb Z\} = \Bbb Z
\iff 1\in \{au+bv, u,v\in \Bbb Z\}.
$$

Comment: I hope this is what you expect when you tagged abstract algebra :)

Comment: Ow, this question is in my abstact algebra textbook.. Did I tag it wrong?

Comment: no, I think it is fine even if I think more of arithmetic ;) actually, the structure 'stable under difference and product by any integer' is called an [ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)).